# How to download a log file from IBM Bluemix?

Tags: ssh, ibm-cloud, cloud-foundry

How can I download a log file from my application deployed in IBM Bluemix into my local computer (Windows)?

```
   cf download APPNAME
```

does not work any more.

I know I could view it via

```
   cf ssh
```

but it's quite big.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can run a remote command with `cf ssh` and direct its output to a local file:
`cf ssh myapp -c "cat app/logfile" > logfile.txt`.

Comment: You can use scp and sftp too.  Ex:  `sftp -P 2222 cf:$(cf app app-name --guid)/0@ssh.bosh-lite.com`.  You just need to replace `ssh.bosh-lite.com` with the DNS name for Bluemix.  You can find that in `cf curl /v2/info`.  More details and examples here -> https://github.com/cloudfoundry/diego-ssh#cloud-foundry-via-cloud-controller-and-uaa

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
cf appname ssh -c "cat logs/filename" >filename
```

Comment: Are you sure? It gives me an error:
'appname' is not a registered command. See 'cf help'

Comment: gosh.. sorry ..no - pls see another reply (your reply is right)